# What's the expected value for a poisoned bottle

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

> There are bottles numbered from 1 to n. Every bottle k has
>   $\frac{1}{k}$ chance of being poisoned. A random bottle is picked (evenly distributed) and
>   is found to be poisoned. What's the expected value for the number of
>   the bottle that was picked?

Here's what I had in mind:

A - The bottle that was picked is poisoned

X - The number of the bottle that was picked

We're searching for:

$$\mathbb{E}[X|A]=\sum_{i=1}^n iP(X=i|A)$$

The problem is calculating the probability. I tried using Bayes' theorem but I can't calculate $P(A)$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't $P(A)$ just the average of $1/k$ for $k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$?

Comment: $E(X \ \vert A) = 1/P(A)$